# 415 Unsupported media type on frontend React.js

Tags: reactjs, jwt, react-hooks, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am working on a fullstack web application using React.js for frontend and Jersey v2.+ for backend. I am developing the user authentication using a JWT. I have a POST method on backend for validating the JWT(if the user is authenticated) which looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/profiles/tokenIsValid")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response checkTokenIsValid(ContainerRequestContext requestContext){
    try{
        Key key = keyGenerator.generateKey();

        String token = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if(token == null){
            return Response.ok(false).build();
        }
        Jws<Claims> verified = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token);
        if(verified == null){
            return Response.ok(false).build();
        }
        String username = verified.getBody().getSubject();
        User verifyUser = authenticate(username);
        if(verifyUser == null){
            return Response.ok(false).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(true).build();
    }catch(Exception e){
        return Response.status(500, e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

When verifying it using postman everything works as expected, being included in the Authorization header the token of the user that is logged in. If the token is valid it returns true, otherwise false..

On the frontend in the App functional component I am using useEffect hook for checking if a token exists or not.

```
 useEffect(() => {
const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
  console.log(token);
  if (token === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
    token = "";
  }
  const tokenRes = await Axios.post("/profiles/tokenIsValid",
  null,
  {headers: {"Authorization": token}}
  );
  console.log(tokenRes.data);
 
};

checkLoggedIn(); }, []);
```

It seems like the failure appears because of the Axios.post request. When trying to debug on the backend whilst refreshing a page on the frontend, nothing happens, it looks like no request is being made to the specified path. Also, I am using proxy in the package.json to the backend path so I do not need to specify the whole path.

This is the error that I get when refreshing a page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parameter in your resource method without any annotations, it is assumed to be the body of the request. And of course ContainerRequestContext is not the body. Since all you need is one header, I would just remove the request context parameter and just use `@HeaderParam("Authorization") String auth` parameter.

And just FYI: You are getting an 415 Media Type Not Supported error because the content-type is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the body parameter is ContainerRequestContext. I'm sure if you looked at the server log, you would see an exception with a message of something like: A MessageBodyReader was not found for type application/x-www-form-urlencoded and Java type ContainerRequestContext.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will take that into account. Although I fixed the problem from the frontend by specifying the Content-Type as 'application/json' in the header of the axios method.